# MySQL2 Ruby gem will not Install 10.6

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I know this has been asked several times, but I searched and I tried many different things and nothing worked.

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for mysql.h... yes
checking for errmsg.h... yes
checking for mysqld_error.h... yes
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-darwin10.6.0 -I/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -DHAVE_RB_THREAD_BLOCKING_REGION -DHAVE_MYSQL_H -DHAVE_ERRMSG_H -DHAVE_MYSQLD_ERROR_H -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE   -I/usr/local/mysql/include  -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386 -fno-common -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wno-long-long  -fno-common -pipe -Wall -funroll-loops  -o client.o -c client.c
In file included from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:4,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:108: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_long’ is negative
/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:112: error: size of array ‘ruby_check_sizeof_voidp’ is negative
In file included from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/intern.h:29,
                 from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/ruby.h:1327,
                 from /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby.h:32,
                 from ./mysql2_ext.h:4,
                 from client.c:1:
/Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/st.h:69: error: size of array ‘st_check_for_sizeof_st_index_t’ is negative
make: *** [client.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/kishinmanglani/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.2.6/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: What command did you try to install it with? Did you supply --with-mysql-config for example?

Comment: I've tried `sudo gem instal mysql2`
and

`sudo gem install mysql2 -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the exact same problems. I resolved them by uninstalling MySQL completely, reinstalling the 64 bit version and installing the `mysql2` gem with options pointing to the MySQL install.

I followed some instructions I found at [petermac.com](http://www.petermac.com/installing-mysql-gem-on-osx-10-6/):

**1. Uninstall MySQL**:

```
sudo rm /usr/local/mysql
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM
sudo rm -rf /Library/PreferencePanes/My*

edit /etc/hostconfig and remove the line MYSQLCOM=-YES-

sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/mysql*
sudo rm -rf /Library/Receipts/MySQL*
```

**2. Install MySQL 64 bit edition**

**3. Install `mysql2` gem**

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install mysql2 -- \
  --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql --with-mysql-lib=/usr/local/mysql/lib \
  --with-mysql-include=/usr/local/mysql/include
```

That should at least get the gem installed :)

Comment: Worked using the latest 10.6 64-bit binary (installer, version 5.5.16-osx10.6-x86_64) for Lion 10.7.1 and the mysql2 gem version 0.3.7.

Comment: This worked for me.. installed fine but rails still complained on building. Symlinking libmysqlclient.18.dylib from /usr/local/mysql/lib/ into /usr/lib and in the mysql2 gem itself fixed that problem.

Comment: It should be emphasized that, as the original blog post indicates, this is an example from a clean 10.6 install where 32-bit was installed but nothing was done with it.

If you have been running mysql 32-bit for a while for other purposes this in most cases will WIPE YOUR DATABASES.  So mysqldump them first, then import them back to the 64 bit version.

Comment: My issue was that i needed to go to the MySQL site and download the right 64 bit version

Comment: this all worked great, though i did also have to remove a dead symlink and point it to the resintalled location .. sudo rm /opt/local/bin/mysql_config && sudo ln -s /opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql_config /opt/local/bin/mysql_config

Answer (score 8):

[This blog post](http://blog.trevorbramble.com/past/2011/5/25/installing_the_mysql2_ruby_gem_on_ubuntu_1104/) solved a similar if not the same problem that I was having.

You need to install `libmysqlclient-dev` in order to build the mysql2 gem.

Comment: This advice will not work for OSX, which is what the original poster is using.

Comment: Totally solved my issue on Debian 6 Squeeze. Had the same issue, simply `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` and you're done ! thanks