# Cannot seem to install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, mysql2

I am trying to install all the dependencies for a rails app I have forked off of github. One of the gems I need is `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'`. However, I get an error when trying to run this. I have almost no clue where to start with this output:

```
Robert-Quinns-MacBook-Pro:talk_your_game robertquinn$ gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.11'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /Users/robertquinn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/robertquinn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/robertquinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/robertquinn/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
Robert-Quinns-MacBook-Pro:talk_your_game robertquinn$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try following the steps [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5404666/2109908), they might help

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have the needed libraries. This works on Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```

I'm not sure about Mac OS.

Take a look at "[Ruby gem mysql2 install failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115126/ruby-gem-mysql2-install-failing)".

Answer (score 0):

Try to install this way:

```
sudo gem install mysql -v '0.3.11' -- —–with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
```

Replace the path by your mysql_config path. If you don't know where it's located, you can try:

```
sudo find / -name mysql_config
```